# Google Penguin recovery time?

Tags: indexing, seo, search-engine, web-crawler

I found yesterday that my site is not showing on Google for its brand name keyword. All pages are still indexed, even homepage shows when i type brand name with description. I don't have any notifications in webmasters tools, so I guess it is Penguin penalty. I had one link in my footer which can be classified as 'unnatural' and i removed it. Site is still young and doesn't have much backlinks (if any). I think everything is fine now. Does anybody know how much time is needed for homepage to start showing in results again? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to give a time frame, just keep working on a solid strategy to create more natural links and hopefully you will see your results begin to improve.